# Where shuold i upload the node api on nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

[In this html file, I Uploaded Angular api. And its working perfectly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTh6G.png)

[Now In which File, That I Want to backend or Node api?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10cIt.png)

Comment: In above images, where shold i upload the backend dist files.

Comment: In above images , how to work with backend files and where i want to deploy backend files.